# Reading property from body with req.body

Tags: node.js, request, body-parser

In the application generating dummy data every second and when I log it with "req.body" the output as below.

```
[
  {
    dataType: 'Number',
    deviceName: 'device1',
    attributeName: 'value',
    min: '1',
    max: '11',
    value: '9.000438216772668',
    ESP_OPS: 'i',
    timestamp: '2020-05-28T20:08:56.544Z'
  }
]
```

However I would like to get "value" in this array. When I try to log it with "req.body.value" it returns "undefined". How can I catch "value" in this array?

Comment: Look at the data - req.body is an *array*.

Comment: Exactly! I want to get "value" from that array

Comment: ...so why do you think an array would have a property named value?

Comment: are you trying to get an array of just the `value` properties of `req.body`?

Comment: I am trying to get "value" property from the object in that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `req.body[0].value`

The [0] statement have the function to reference the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`req.body` returns an array. In this case the array only has 1 element (which is the json object that you want access to). In JavaScript array indices start at 0, therefore you need to write`req.body[0]`